# Make Actions to Specific Elements that clicked on Accordion Menu[Jquery]

Tags: jquery

Well maybe the answer is simple..but i am new at learning Jquery.
I am trying to make a vertical Accordion Menu.
I have an UL and some list inside. (Basic Menus)
Every List contain a H3 Title and a new Unorderd List with some list inside.(Sub-menus)
Like [this one :](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/vertical-accordion-menu-using-jquery-css3)

Every main-menu when clicked opens vertically the Submenus.
Only extra i wanted was a plus(+) sign on the left that changes to minus when clicked.
Because i already use a background, i choosed this sign to be img not background.
Problem is that in click ALL the signs change not the specific that clicked.

Please see JSFiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/stefanos10G/9vLvm/)

JQUERY CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#accordion-menu h3.has-slide").click(function(){
//slide up all the link lists
$("#accordion-menu ul ul").slideUp();
$(".acc-open-sub").attr('src',"images/acc-plus.png");
//slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
{
  $(this).next().slideDown();
  $(".acc-open-sub").attr('src',"images/acc-min.png");
}
});
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#accordion-menu h3.has-slide").click(function(){
   $("#accordion-menu ul ul").slideUp();
   $(".acc-open-sub").attr('src',"http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jensenl/images/BoxedPlusSign.gif");
  if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
  {
   $(this).next().slideDown();
   $(this).find(".acc-open-sub").attr('src',"http://findicons.com/files/icons/1689/splashy/16/remove_minus_sign_small.png");
  }
 });
});
```

While opening slide you should change minus image for only clicked child element.

```
$(".acc-open-sub").attr('src',"http://findicons.com/files/icons/1689/splashy/16/remove_minus_sign_small.png");
```

Changed to

```
$(this).find(".acc-open-sub").attr('src',"http://findicons.com/files/icons/1689/splashy/16/remove_minus_sign_small.png");
```